# Google with oauth 2

Tags: php, oauth

I am trying  to connect with google via oauth V2

I make http request

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=4/55Ji5pVGxrhCUB3yMu6BYdi2qARQ&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.choozon.net%2Foauth2callback&client_id=408311227080.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Ffeed%2Fatom&client_secret=********&grant_type=authorization_code
```

why the response is

```
Method Not Allowed     Error 405
```

Comment: this means you are not being authorized by Google? have you got request token successfully?

Comment: I've just got the code  after  authorizing with google ...and now i'm trying to get the token ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP 405 means that you are trying to use a verb that is not allowed by the resource. For example using a `POST` on a read-only `GET` resource or `PUT` on a write resource that only accepts `POST`s.

Comment: thanks my friend, the problem was fixed just by using curl instead of file_get_contents, thanks ...

Comment: Yep - for me it was google and it was expecting a POST not a GET