# Google oauth 2.0 refreshing access token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, oauth

How to get a new access token in Google Oauth 2.0?

I tried this:

```
    NSString * urlString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=my_client_id&client_secret=my_client_secret&refresh_token=%@&grant_type=refresh_token",auth.refreshToken];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString1];   
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
```

But result is: Method Not Allowed (Error 405)

Maybe there is another way to get new access token?

Please help! 
Thanks!

Comment: Please tell how to get a new access token, maybe from keychain? I tried but return result is (null).

Answer (score 0):

please use following code to get access token in Google Plus

First Replase you **- (NSString *)description** method in **GTMOAuth2Authentication.h** file and you will surely get G+ Acccess token

```
 - (NSString *)description 
 {
        NSArray *props = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"accessToken",nil];//[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"accessToken", @"refreshToken",@"code", @"assertion", @"expirationDate", @"errorString",nil];
       NSMutableString *valuesStr = [NSMutableString string];
       NSString *separator = @"";
       for (NSString *prop in props) {
       id result = [self valueForKey:prop];
       if (result)
       {
          [valuesStr appendFormat:@"%@",result];
          separator = @", ";
      }
    }

 return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",valuesStr];
}
```

**in .h file**

```
@class GPPSignInButton;
@interface GPlusView : UIViewController <GPPSignInDelegate>
{
      IBOutlet GPPSignInButton *signInButton;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet GPPSignInButton *signInButton;
```

**in .m file**

```
 signInButton_.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = TRUE;
 signInButton_.delegate = self;

 signInButton_.clientID = [SamacharAppDelegate clientID];
 signInButton_.scope = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
                       nil];


 -(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error
 {
     if (error) {
           NSLog(@"Error = %@",error.localizedDescription);
           return;
     }
     NSLog("Auth Data = %@",auth);

   /* Auth Data =  {accessToken="ya29.AHES6ZQYLmSBc9n4pLj9U8OQrFoTDZnGLH8okPkxbda7B0Q", refreshToken="1/puItTB-sqHupfp9qPCKcb6_gWUjgcxwzc9TKJvUwMEI", expirationDate="2012-11-24 13:30:55 +0000"}  */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 405 means that you are trying to use a verb that is not allowed by the resource. For example using a `POST` on a read-only `GET` resource or `PUT` on a write resource that only accepts `POST`s.

See [abraham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800336/google-with-oauth-2/9810563#9810563) : [Google with oauth 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800336/google-with-oauth-2/9810563#9810563)